# Getting tab navigation events in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on an extension to detect youtube videos running in background and log them.

What I am not able to get from the high-level `tabs` API is the navigation event for a tab.

For eg, when I go to **youtube.com**, I can get that event from "ready" event.

But when I click a video link to load it in the same tab, I don't get any event. Also, when a new video automatically loads after the last one ends (Autoplay), I don't get any event.

How do I get these changes?

My current hack is to just loop through all the open tabs and check for "youtube.com/watch?v=" substring every 10-20 seconds.

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var listen = 1;


var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "activate",
  label: "Start Listening",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: toggleListen
});

//check tabs
var { setInterval } = require("sdk/timers");

setInterval(function() {

    suburl = "www.youtube.com/watch"
    for (let tab of tabs){
        if(tab.url.indexOf(suburl)>-1){
            console.log("tab: ",tab.url);
        }
    }
  console.log("\n--------------------------------\n\n");
}, 15000)
```

Comment: Also listen for the "activate" and "pageshow" events, and you should be covered.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

const YOUTUBE_URI = /^https:\/\/www.youtube.com/;

tabs.on("load", function(tab) {
  if (YOUTUBE_URI.test(tab.url)) {
    console.log('tabWatcher: ' + t.url + ' is shown for the first time');
  }
});

tabs.on("activate", function(tab) {
  if (tab.readyState=='complete') {
    if (YOUTUBE_URI.test(tab.url)) {
      console.log('tabWatcher: ' + t.url + ' is shown again');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't give any output. Any idea?

Comment: @goelakash You must open the "browser console" and enable "log" (the grey thing).

Comment: I am using the plugin dev environment, so I get console log outputs in terminal (jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox). I get console logs from my code.

Comment: Maybe your URI doesn't begin with `https://www.youtube.com`. If you want to debug the code, you may comment out the condition on the URI...